# Unable to get Edit button in selenium c# webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

From the html code I am unable to get the edit button in selenium c#

```
<button class="pt-buttonbase pt-button pt-bordered pt-icon-and-text" data-iconurl="../content/icons/Edit.png" data-bind="click: $root.editTemplate" data-toolkit="button">
```

Comment: You'll need to post your html code, and what you've tried with your c# code, before we have enough context to help you.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not knowing what you've tried and haven't tried, I would suggest xpath.  Assuming you have a WebDriver variable, `Driver`:

```
WebElement EditButton = Driver.FindElement(
    By.XPath("//button[@data-iconurl='../content/icons/Edit.png']"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Ask whomever the developer is to give the button a unique ID. Then search it by ID.

Answer (score 0):

If you can provide some HTML it'll be better. Note that when you are using XPath with *class* - you'll receive *first* element matching your condition. And even if it's correct - you will get not required button. In this case use indexing e.g. [1].

Answer (score 0):

I like using CssSelector:

You might not need to use all 4 class names, but this will work:

```
By.CssSelector(".pt-buttonbase.pt-button.pt-bordered.pt-icon-and-text"));
```

You can always check in your browsers console to see if classes are unique using JQuery like this:

```
$(".pt-buttonbase")
```

If that is not unique you can keep adding the other class names until you only get one object as a response.